# Unable to read input in while loop, not sure why

Tags: c++

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
    string s = "";
    string disliked = "Broccoli";

    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    while (cin >> s);
    {
        if (s == disliked) cout << "BLEEP\n";
        else cout << s << '\n';

        cout << "Enter a word: ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So my code is not getting past the cin >> s statement in my while loop and I'm not sure why. I stepped through my program and my program gets stuck on the cin >> s statement like it didn't read the string from input even though I can't see why not.

Comment: See if you're able to read from a file. Or if only reading from standard terminal gives the problem.

Comment: Is your application crashing? Are you using mingw on windows? If so you're likely loading a different standard library dll than the one that came with your compiler

Comment: `while (cin >> s);` the `;` at the end of the line is making the code into an infinite loop until `cin` hits EOF.

Comment: @Eljay that should be posted as an answer

Comment: Side note: You have duplicated the line `cout << "Enter a word: ";`, which is usually considered bad programming style. You can prevent this code duplication by changing your loop to an infinite loop `while ( true )` with a conditional `break` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you accidentally made an infinite loop:

```c
while (cin >> s); // this semicolon
{
    // this is now a separate piece of code not in a loop, but after the loop finishes
}
```

The problem is, that the loop won't finish until cin receives an EOF.

This can be solved by simply removing the extra semicolon.

I have found that using the following syntax helps make these types of issues easier to spot:

```c
while (...); { // problem here
    ...
}
```

If you want to know more about why this isn't a syntax error, check out the "nested scopes" section of [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope).